# Не открывается exe с qcustomplot

Tags: qt, виджет

Сделала приложение с графиком с помощью виджета qcustomplot. 
Потом сделала ехе файл, скинула туда все файлы из release, все как надо, вроде
Но при открытии ехе файла выходит ошибка

```
Не удается продолжить выполнение кода, поскольку система не обнаружила Qt5Widgets.dll ...
```

Если я кидаю в ту папку файл "Qt5Widgets.dll", возникает новая ошибка

```
Точка входа в процедуру не найдена в библиотеке DLL ...
```

Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Comment: Точка входа не найдена в какой библиотеке? Qt5Widgets.dll из какой папки в релиз клали?

Comment: Из папки bin...

Comment: Было бы неплохо ответить на все вопросы, которые я задал, а не только на последний

Comment: Извините. "Точка входа в процедуру  _ZN6QDebug9putStringEPK5Qcharj не найдена в библиотеке DLL ... (дальше идет путь к файлу)"

Comment: Как вам удалось дать самую бесполезную информацию из сообщения об ошибке? Для диагностики нужно название библиотеки, в которой не найдена функция. Вообще судя по симптомам вы добавили не те библиотеки, самая частая ошибка - взять библиотеки от QtCreator, который собран другим компилятором, нежели сам Qt. Ищите нужные библиотеки в папке с Qt, в моем случае, например, это `C:\Qt\5.11.1\mingw53_32\bin`

Comment: в конце пути была так же библиотека Qt5Widgets.dll
Даже после того, как скинула из пути к компилятору Qt5Widgets.dll в папку release, тоже не заработало
Даже, когда скинула в саму папку bin все  из release